# I'm trying to do a basic audio recorder with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have some homework to do. I need to create an audio recorder that basically starts recording and then stop recording. So I have a basic graphic interface with tkinter, with 2 buttons, one that is supposed to start and the other to stop the recording.
I have the following code to record the sound.

```
def record():

    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        CHANNELS = 2
        RATE = 44100
        CHUNK = 1024

    print ("recording...")

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # start recording
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    frames = []

    while v == 1:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)


    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
    print ("recording successfull\n")
    return_data = [frames, stream, audio]
    return return_data
```

As I have two buttons, I need to have two functions, one that starts the recording, one that stops it so I need to split the record() function in two parts. But I can't figure out how to do that.
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with event handling. User click on the start button generates the onClick event on the button and runs the assigned handler function which manages running recording. The same with stop button. 
[Here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) you can find more about doing it in tkinter.